# Parsing Specific CSS with Regex

Tags: c#, .net, css, regex

I'm struggling to come up right regex to solve my problem. I need to parse the variables and their values out of this Sass file. Variables always start with $ and end with :, and their values begin after the : and end with ;, much like CSS.

I'm using .Net's regex parser, and testing against this useful regex tool: http://derekslager.com/blog/posts/2007/09/a-better-dotnet-regular-expression-tester.ashx

I'm able to find the variables just fine with this match string

```
\$[\w\d-]*:
```

However, how can I find the matching value pair and not pick up the false positives from the other css, such as "10px"

```
/*
Theme Name:   Huff
*/

// Particle Imports
@import "blueprint";

// Blueprint Variables
$blueprint_grid_margin: 10px;

// Site Specific Styles
$primary-color: #a1bfc2;
$link-color: #AFBDD2;

html {
  font-smooth: always;
}


body.bp {
  @include ui;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  background-color: $secondary-color;
}
```

Comment: Just use an existing CSS parser?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use groups like this.

```
\$([\w\d-]*):\s*(.*)?\s*;
```

Then match all and group 1 has the name while group 2 has the value for each match.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
(\$[\w\d-]*):\s*([^;]+);
```

$1 will contain the variable name, $2 will contain the value. The value will include any quotes, whitespace, etc., other than whitespace that is trimmed directly after the ":".

Comment: When I run it against http://derekslager.com/blog/posts/2007/09/a-better-dotnet-regular-expression-tester.ashx I get 0 matches.

Comment: You need a * instead of a ? for the `[\w\d-]` class

Comment: I pasted from the wrong clipboard buffer, fixed... but looks like I'm too late.